# How to remove error 127 after make command

Tags: wireless, make, adhoc

I am installing `olsrd` for one of my project on ad-hoc network and not able to proceed further due to the following error:-

```
yuvraj@yuvi-PC ~/olsrd-0.6.8 $ make
[BISON] src/cfgparser/oparse.c
/bin/sh: 1: bison: not found
make: *** [src/cfgparser/oparse.c] Error 127
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a source tarball download or a SCM checkout URL?

Answer (score 1):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bison libbison-dev flex libfl-dev
cd ~/olsrd-0.6.8
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package `bison`.

Comment: I installed the package already. I am still getting this error.

Comment: Do you really still get the error `bison: not found` or just a similar one?